# Android: How to display an app in the contact profile screen (under connections)

Tags: android

I have an app that can show a stream of tweets from a twitter user. 
I want to add the app to the device contact screen so when the user opens a contact there will be a button for my app in the same page under connections (like the button WhatsApp added to my contacts). So when the user clicks it my app activity will be called containing some info about the contact that was clicked. Then, I'll make the connection between the contact info and his tweeter account in my app and display his tweets.

How can i implement this? Where do i begin?

Comment: Hi did you fix your issue?..If yes, then please share your code..

Comment: @ldan: did you found the solution. how did you accomplished your task.

Comment: @Ankxx13 I did not. The task was canceled so I left it. I guess you need to implement a SyncAdapter.. But I did not got into that issue so I cant help much.

Comment: @Idan ok. thank you for your time. i will update you if i find some good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add your own mime type for the data associated with the contact. Then you will have to register for that mime type in your app.

You can see the [sync adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Answer (score 2):

This link would definitely help you out.. http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/